# Indexed full-text search count in MongoDB is exremely slow... and what is "TEXT" stage?

Tags: mongodb

So I have MongoDB 3.0.7 running on an Amazon r3.xlarge box (4 cores, 30GB of RAM, 80GB SSD) and have stored about 40GB worth of semi-complex json data, about 7 million documents. It looks like this:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5665f1fef8adb3ee597af375"),
  "some_other_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "meta": {
    ...
  },
  "raw": {
    ...
    "text": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    ...
  },
  "__v": 0,
  "created_at": ISODate("2015-12-07T20:54:10Z")
}
```

I've indexed one text field using the following command:

```
db.messages.createIndex({"raw.text":"text"})
```

This is what the index looks like:

```
    {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                    "_fts" : "text",
                    "_ftsx" : 1
            },
            "name" : "raw.text_text",
            "ns" : "DBDB.messages",
            "weights" : {
                    "raw.text" : 1
            },
            "default_language" : "english",
            "language_override" : "language",
            "textIndexVersion" : 2
    }
```

This yielded an index size of about 3GB for my 40GB data. In addition, I have 4 more indexes on this collection, all numeric. In total I have 5 indexes on this collection and the total size of the index is 4GB.

I'm performing a count() operation on a query such as:

```
db.messages.find({$text:{$search:"mouse"}}).count()
```

What I've been finding is that the time it takes for this count to return is more or less proportional to the number of jsons that match the find() criteria. For a condition that returns a bunch of results, like 5 million, it takes at least 30 minutes! Again, I'm not returning the result. I'm simply trying to find out how many of my documents have a single keyword in it.

This is what I get from explain(). According to this link (https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/explain-results/) "TEXT" is not one of the stages. I don't really know what it means and google search is getting me nothing. It does mention my text index so I'm hoping my full-text index is being used in this count() operation.

```
> db.messages.explain().find({$text:{$search:"mouse"}}).count()
{
        "queryPlanner" : {
                "plannerVersion" : 1,
                "namespace" : "DBDB.messages",
                "indexFilterSet" : false,
                "parsedQuery" : {
                        "$text" : {
                                "$search" : "mouse",
                                "$language" : ""
                        }
                },
                "winningPlan" : {
                        "stage" : "COUNT",
                        "inputStage" : {
                                "stage" : "TEXT",
                                "indexPrefix" : {

                                },
                                "indexName" : "raw.text_text",
                                "parsedTextQuery" : {

                                }
                        }
                },
                "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
        },
        "serverInfo" : {
                "host" : "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "port" : 27017,
                "version" : "3.0.7",
                "gitVersion" : "6ce7cbe8c6b899552dadd907604559806aa2e9bd"
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

I have 30GB of physical RAM on my box and the indexes total 4GB. I see that when I perform these queries, mongod is using almost 8GB. So I'm assuming that it loads all indexes entirely in memory. So I'd expect almost every find().count() operation to return within seconds if it's running on the index. I'm not performing any other database operations like inserts or other queries. I took everything else out to isolate just the database.

I'm obviously doing something wrong here but I feel like I've done everything according to what I've read online. I'm very new to MongoDB, though.

Finally, this is the the currentOp() output after running the query for 5 mins or so:

```
> db.currentOp()
{
        "inprog" : [
                {
                        "desc" : "conn1",
                        "threadId" : "0x316f1e0",
                        "connectionId" : 1,
                        "opid" : 94,
                        "active" : true,
                        "secs_running" : 539,
                        "microsecs_running" : NumberLong(539798074),
                        "op" : "query",
                        "ns" : "DBDB.messages",
                        "query" : {
                                "count" : "messages",
                                "query" : {
                                        "$text" : {
                                                "$search" : "mouse"
                                        }
                                },
                                "fields" : {

                                }
                        },
                        "planSummary" : "TEXT {}",
                        "client" : "127.0.0.1:37784",
                        "numYields" : 3478,
                        "locks" : {
                                "Global" : "r",
                                "MMAPV1Journal" : "r",
                                "Database" : "r",
                                "Collection" : "R"
                        },
                        "waitingForLock" : false,
                        "lockStats" : {
                                "Global" : {
                                        "acquireCount" : {
                                                "r" : NumberLong(6958)
                                        }
                                },
                                "MMAPV1Journal" : {
                                        "acquireCount" : {
                                                "r" : NumberLong(3479)
                                        }
                                },
                                "Database" : {
                                        "acquireCount" : {
                                                "r" : NumberLong(3479)
                                        }
                                },
                                "Collection" : {
                                        "acquireCount" : {
                                                "R" : NumberLong(3479)
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                }
        ]
}
```

EDIT: Adding "executionStats" output
EDIT: Upgraded to MongoDB 3.2.1. These are the new execution Stats. The previous execution stats were using a different search word because "mouse" took way too long. This time, I let the "mouse query finish" and you can see that it took almost 40 mins.

```
> db.messages.explain("executionStats").find({$text:{$search:"mouse"}}).count()
{
        "queryPlanner" : {
                "plannerVersion" : 1,
                "namespace" : "DBDB.messages",
                "indexFilterSet" : false,
                "parsedQuery" : {
                        "$text" : {
                                "$search" : "mouse",
                                "$language" : "english",
                                "$caseSensitive" : false,
                                "$diacriticSensitive" : false
                        }
                },
                "winningPlan" : {
                        "stage" : "COUNT",
                        "inputStage" : {
                                "stage" : "TEXT",
                                "indexPrefix" : {

                                },
                                "indexName" : "raw.text_text",
                                "parsedTextQuery" : {
                                        "terms" : [
                                                "mous"
                                        ],
                                        "negatedTerms" : [ ],
                                        "phrases" : [ ],
                                        "negatedPhrases" : [ ]
                                },
                                "inputStage" : {
                                        "stage" : "TEXT_MATCH",
                                        "inputStage" : {
                                                "stage" : "TEXT_OR",
                                                "inputStage" : {
                                                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                                        "keyPattern" : {
                                                                "_fts" : "text",
                                                                "_ftsx" : 1
                                                        },
                                                        "indexName" : "raw.text_text",
                                                        "isMultiKey" : true,
                                                        "isUnique" : false,
                                                        "isSparse" : false,
                                                        "isPartial" : false,
                                                        "indexVersion" : 1,
                                                        "direction" : "backward",
                                                        "indexBounds" : {

                                                        }
                                                }
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                },
                "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
        },
        "executionStats" : {
                "executionSuccess" : true,
                "nReturned" : 0,
                "executionTimeMillis" : 2305641,
                "totalKeysExamined" : 5984163,
                "totalDocsExamined" : 5984163,
                "executionStages" : {
                        "stage" : "COUNT",
                        "nReturned" : 0,
                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 2277920,
                        "works" : 11968329,
                        "advanced" : 0,
                        "needTime" : 11968328,
                        "needYield" : 0,
                        "saveState" : 179094,
                        "restoreState" : 179094,
                        "isEOF" : 1,
                        "invalidates" : 0,
                        "nCounted" : 5984163,
                        "nSkipped" : 0,
                        "inputStage" : {
                                "stage" : "TEXT",
                                "nReturned" : 5984163,
                                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 2276450,
                                "works" : 11968329,
                                "advanced" : 5984163,
                                "needTime" : 5984165,
                                "needYield" : 0,
                                "saveState" : 179094,
                                "restoreState" : 179094,
                                "isEOF" : 1,
                                "invalidates" : 0,
                                "indexPrefix" : {

                                },
                                "indexName" : "raw.text_text",
                                "parsedTextQuery" : {
                                        "terms" : [
                                                "mous"
                                        ],
                                        "negatedTerms" : [ ],
                                        "phrases" : [ ],
                                        "negatedPhrases" : [ ]
                                },
                                "inputStage" : {
                                        "stage" : "TEXT_MATCH",
                                        "nReturned" : 5984163,
                                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 2275970,
                                        "works" : 11968329,
                                        "advanced" : 5984163,
                                        "needTime" : 5984165,
                                        "needYield" : 0,
                                        "saveState" : 179094,
                                        "restoreState" : 179094,
                                        "isEOF" : 1,
                                        "invalidates" : 0,
                                        "docsRejected" : 0,
                                        "inputStage" : {
                                                "stage" : "TEXT_OR",
                                                "nReturned" : 5984163,
                                                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 2275550,
                                                "works" : 11968329,
                                                "advanced" : 5984163,
                                                "needTime" : 5984165,
                                                "needYield" : 0,
                                                "saveState" : 179094,
                                                "restoreState" : 179094,
                                                "isEOF" : 1,
                                                "invalidates" : 0,
                                                "docsExamined" : 5984163,
                                                "inputStage" : {
                                                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                                        "nReturned" : 5984163,
                                                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 11520,
                                                        "works" : 5984164,
                                                        "advanced" : 5984163,
                                                        "needTime" : 0,
                                                        "needYield" : 0,
                                                        "saveState" : 179094,
                                                        "restoreState" : 179094,
                                                        "isEOF" : 1,
                                                        "invalidates" : 0,
                                                        "keyPattern" : {
                                                                "_fts" : "text",
                                                                "_ftsx" : 1
                                                        },
                                                        "indexName" : "raw.text_text",
                                                        "isMultiKey" : true,
                                                        "isUnique" : false,
                                                        "isSparse" : false,
                                                        "isPartial" : false,
                                                        "indexVersion" : 1,
                                                        "direction" : "backward",
                                                        "indexBounds" : {

                                                        },
                                                        "keysExamined" : 5984163,
                                                        "dupsTested" : 5984163,
                                                        "dupsDropped" : 0,
                                                        "seenInvalidated" : 0
                                                }
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                }
        },
        "serverInfo" : {
                "host" : "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "port" : 27017,
                "version" : "3.2.1",
                "gitVersion" : "a14d55980c2cdc565d4704a7e3ad37e4e535c1b2"
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: Can you try printing the `executionStats` to get more details.

Comment: Yep, I just added at the very bottom of my question.

Comment: Another note is that the text field contains a mixed bag of different languages and many of them do not use Latin alphabets. e.g. Chinese, Russian, Arabic, etc. I can't imagine that affecting the performance dramatically, though. I edited my question again towards the top to show the actual index.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe your query is using index.

Here is how it looks on my machine.

```
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "test.grades",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "$text" : {
                "$search" : "homework",
                "$language" : "english",
                "$caseSensitive" : false,
                "$diacriticSensitive" : false
            }
        },
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "COUNT",
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "TEXT",
                "indexPrefix" : {

                },
                "indexName" : "scores.type_text",
                "parsedTextQuery" : {
                    "terms" : [
                        "homework"
                    ],
                    "negatedTerms" : [ ],
                    "phrases" : [ ],
                    "negatedPhrases" : [ ]
                },
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "TEXT_MATCH",
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "TEXT_OR",
                        "inputStage" : {
                            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                            "keyPattern" : {
                                "_fts" : "text",
                                "_ftsx" : 1
                            },
                            "indexName" : "scores.type_text",
                            "isMultiKey" : true,
                            "isUnique" : false,
                            "isSparse" : false,
                            "isPartial" : false,
                            "indexVersion" : 1,
                            "direction" : "backward",
                            "indexBounds" : {

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
    },
    "serverInfo" : {
        "host" : "xxxxxxxxxxx",
        "port" : 27017,
        "version" : "3.2.1",
        "gitVersion" : "a14d55980c2cdc565d4704a7e3ad37e4e535c1b2"
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

You can see it's using IXSCAN. if possible, please drop your index and re-create. I'd personally like to use ensureIndex to perform this action.

you may also want to get better picture of what's going on with more verbosity by using `db.messages.explain("executionStats").find({$text:{$search:"mouse"}}).count()`

EDIT: index on my machine looks like:

```
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "_fts" : "text",
        "_ftsx" : 1
    },
    "name" : "scores.type_text",
    "ns" : "test.grades",
    "weights" : {
        "scores.type" : 1
    },
    "default_language" : "english",
    "language_override" : "language",
    "textIndexVersion" : 3
}
```

Comment: I used createIndex instead ensureIndex. According the Mongo docs, ensureIndex has been deprecated and I should use createIndex instead. Do you know a good reason why I should use ensureIndex? Also, I just updated my question to include the output of executionStats.

Comment: hmm, I'm confused. new log is showing partial information. It should contain multiple inputStages. Regarding ensureIndex vs createIndex, both are fine. I'm little bit old school so got used to with ensureIndex and it works fine for me. Is it possible for you to upgrade MongoDB to latest? I see your query takes 140 mills which is not bad.

Comment: I have added above how my text index looks like.

Comment: I upgraded to 3.2.1 and my index looks just like yours. The result hasn't changed, though. I also ran "executionStats" on the actual search term this time so the execution time of almost 40 mins are correct.

Comment: question: Have you actually performed a text search on a collection of this magnitude? 40GB collection size and ~7 million documents. If I run this on a 500k collection, all my text searches come back within a few seconds.

Comment: 40 min is not normal at all. to your second question, no I haven't to that magnitude but to roughly 10GB. if you don't mind can you post a sample document mimicking somewhat real one? I'll try to replicate your environment but of course not in AWS.

Comment: Ok, MongoDB is struggling with full text performance issues. I  see that there are bunch of defects are opened related to it in MongoDB jira. https://jira.mongodb.org, I have created one too. In  my case, I have roughly 3.2 million documents and it's taking me over 100 seconds to return any result.

Comment: Saleem, thanks for helping me tracking this down. I'm just storing tweets you get from their public API. If you look at my OP, the json structure, under raw is the tweet json verbatim. Then, under meta, I just have two inconsequential fields like created_date and some ID. Also, I'm not actually searching for the text mouse but something that occurs very frequently.

Comment: @ComputerSoftwareGuy I got update from MongoDB. They marked it as feature :) and pushed down it to backlog so you have to wait for some time in future.

Comment: thanks for letting me know and trying to help me through this. I think our issues are a bit different but probably related. I've moved on to using Elastic for full-text search.